# Why is "dare" used in "One of you dare not fight with him"?

Tags: word-usage, british-english, phrase-usage, subcontinental-english, class-based-usage

The sentence is :

1. One of you dare not fight with him.
2. One of you dares not fight with him.

I have read that we should use singular verb with "one of +plural noun+ singular verb" but here *dares* is not correct usage. So what is the correct usage?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with *one of*.

In some dialects of English, *dare* is a semi-modal verb. What this means is that in negative sentences, and only in negative sentences, it isn't conjugated, and it doesn't take *to* after it. (The verb *need* is the other semi-modal that can act this way.)

> He dare not oppose the king.
>   He dares to oppose the king.

In other dialects of English, *dare* is a regular verb:

> He doesn't dare to oppose the king.

But these sentences are always wrong:

> *He dares not ***to*** oppose the king.
>   *He dare oppose the king.

(Although the last one would be fine if you put a question mark at the end of it, because that makes it count as a negative sentence.)

> He dare oppose the king?

So the possible correct sentences (depending on your dialect) for your question are are:

> One of you dare not fight with him.
>   One of you doesn't dare fight with him.
>   One of you doesn't dare to fight with him.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am just a beginner . Can you please tell me when to use "Dares "and when to use "dare " . with some few examples?

Comment: Easiest solution: treat *dare to* as a regular verb. *"One of you does not dare to fight with him."*

Comment: I'm not so sure about the first 'always wrong' example actually being wrong: "He dares not to oppose the king". I can imagine this working in an Elizabethan accent: "He dares not to oppose the king but rages foul against the prince."

Comment: @Lawrence - Still needs to drop the *to* to my ear.

Comment: @Jim [Here's](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=dPYSAAAAIAAJ&pg=RA2-PA591&dq=%22dares+not+to%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdrbj9u7nXAhXEwLwKHQ_vAAIQ6AEIVDAI#v=onepage&q=%22dares%20not%20to%22&f=false) a literary example.